# Autohotkey restart script when time is up

Tags: autohotkey

I have an infinite loop script running. I want to run it during night without monitoring it (it gets stuck once in a while at something unavoidable).

So I need code to restart the script if 4 minutes are done. ( Script will finish within 3 minutes 100% ). Also, it should not restart before 3 minutes..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) command.

```
SetTimer, restartScript, -240000  ;run the timer just once after 240000 milliseconds

;main script here
;....
;return

restartScript:
Reload
return
```